# linux c++ how to call function after specific time interval

Tags: c++, linux, timer

Let's say I have some function func() in my program, and I need it to be called after some specific delay. So far I have googled it and ended up with folowing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>   /* for setitimer */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for pause */
#include <signal.h>     /* for signal */

void func()
{
    printf("func() called\n");
}

bool startTimer(double seconds)
{
    itimerval it_val;
    double integer, fractional;

    integer = (int)seconds;
    fractional = seconds - integer;

    it_val.it_value.tv_sec = integer;
    it_val.it_value.tv_usec = fractional * 1000000;
    it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;

    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1)
        return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if (signal(SIGALRM, (void(*)(int))func) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
        exit(1);
    }

    startTimer(1.5);

    while(1)
        pause();

    return 0;
}
```

And it works, but the problem is that settimer() causes func() to be called repeatedly with interval of 1.5 sec. And what I need, is to call func() just once.
Can someone tell me how to do this? Maybe, I need some additional parameters to settimer() ?

Note: time interval should be precise, because this program will play midi music later.

Comment: What's wrong with a hard delay?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , if you mean using sleep() function, than problem is that it does not provide precise intervals of time, that is inacceptable for playing music

Comment: What about just stopping the timer in `func()`?

Comment: I'd strongly urge you to consider these alternatives: [sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) (instead of "signal()"), and [timer_create](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create).  Look at the sample code in the timer_create link.

Comment: It's not a great idea to call functions from inside a signal handler which is what you will end up doing above.  The timer_create family gives you the option of calling your function from a separate thread instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need the program to be doing other things, you can simply sleep for the time allotted.

If you need to use the alarm, you can install the alarm to be processed once.

From the man page:

> struct timeval it_interval
>
> This is the period between successive timer interrupts. If zero, the alarm will only be sent once.

Instead of your code:

```
it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;
```

I'd set:

```
it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
it_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
```

In addition to it_val.it_value which you already set. What you've done is use the same values for both structures, and that is why you see a repeated interval.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I set interval to zero, as you suggested and it worked :)